# Map of Nadis, Chakras and Marmas in Human body

Tags: body, ayurveda, nadi

It is said that there are 72,000 Nadis in the Human body. Is there any sophisticated Map indicating the Chakras, important Nadis and Marma points in the Human anatomical diagram ?

Comment: Perhaps you would get closer to what you look for if you read through the various acupuncture points?

Comment: You can ask Ayurveda related questions here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102499/ayurveda

Answer (score 1):

In *Saundarya Lahari of Sri Sankaracarya* by Swami Tapasyananda there is an an Appendix II titled *Anatomical and Physiological Basis of Raja Yoga* by Dr. J. K. Sarkar. In it he gives a detailed map showing how the yogic centers and chakras relate to the human body. Among some of the results he states the following correspondences for the lotuses:

> 1. Muladhara--Inferior Hypogastric Plexus (pelvicplexus).
> 2. Svadhisthana--Superior Hypogastric Plexus.
> 3. Manipura--Coeliac or Solar Plexus.
> 4. Anahata--Cardiac Plexus.
> 5. Visuddha--plexuses connecting superior, middle and inferior cervical ganglia.
> 6. Ajna--Interior carotid plexus.
> 7. Sahasrara--Pineal Gland.

Comment: The chakra locations are widely known, but not the Nadis. The documentation of anatomy of the spiritual body is poor possibly due to reasons like secrecy. For example what exactly is the course and path of the idagala, pingala and sushumna nadis?

Comment: There is no secrecy involved. Those details as to the course of the ida, pingala, and sushumna are gone into detail in the book I referenced. Unfortunately there  is a LOT of detail and much too much for me to put into an answer. In short, however, there is no direct correlation between the Ida and Pingala and the Anatomical Nervous System (ANS). The doctor says: "But, although the two sympathetic trunks meeting at the Ganglion Impar conform to the description...the existing knowledge of  ANS does not support the the idea that the right sympathetic trunk transmits the afferent, and the...

Comment: ..left trunk transmits the efferent impulses, nor is there any crossing of the sympathetic nerve fibres at the base of the brain...Thus,..., it is difficult to fit in the Ida and Pingala concept with any definite autonomic pathway of the nervous system."